# Django not able display the pdf file from Amazon S3, but able to upload to the amazon S3

Tags: django, amazon-s3

i am trying to display my pdf list that had upload to the amazon S3, and i had make sure the connection between django and amazon S3 is correct, cause i am able to upload pdf file to S3 by using admin interface. Currently i am trying to display the list of file that had upload to S3 in a table. I had try to display the pdf file list from S3 and nothing show, but the print statement is able to show when i select the Link of "View PDF List", but no data is displaying at the table that should be display.
Now the table is just empty and notthing will be display on the table. i had try looking out, did not find something i think it will help me.

demo of the table. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVAbi.png)

following is my code.

views.py

```
views.py

def upload_pdf(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PDFDocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            pdf_doc = form.save(commit=False)

            # Upload the PDF file to S3
            s3 = boto3.client('s3')
            pdf_file = request.FILES['pdf_file']
            s3.upload_fileobj(pdf_file, settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME, f'pdfs/{pdf_file.name}')

            # Set the S3 URL for the PDF file
            pdf_doc.pdf_file.name = f'pdfs/{pdf_file.name}'
            pdf_doc.save()
            return redirect('pdf_list')
    else:
        form = PDFDocumentForm()
    return render(request, 'customPage/uploadPage.html', {'form': form})



def getDataFromS3(bucket_name):
    print('get for display_pdf_list function')
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id='i hide it', aws_secret_access_key='i hide it', region_name = 'ap-southeast-2')

    try:
        response = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name)
        contents = response.get('Contents', [])
        s3_data = []

        for obj in contents:
            key = obj['Key']
            response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key)
            pdf_content = response['Body'].read()
            
            print('saw this mean it call')

            # Specify the appropriate encoding for your content
            try:
                pdf_content_decoded = pdf_content.decode('utf-8')
            except UnicodeDecodeError:
                # Handle the decoding error by skipping this object or using a different encoding
                pdf_content_decoded = 'Unable to decode content'

            s3_data.append({'title': key, 'content': pdf_content_decoded})

        return s3_data
    except NoCredentialsError:
        print("Credentials not available")


    
def display_pdf_list(request):
    print('Inside display_pdf_list function')
    bucket_name = 'fyphrcvstorage'
    S3_data = getDataFromS3(bucket_name)

    print('Inside display_pdf_list function 2222222')

    return render(request, 'customPage/viewCVpage.html', {'S3_data': S3_data})
```

models.py

```
models.py

class PDFDocument(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pdf_file = models.FileField(upload_to='pdfs/')
    # pdf_file = models.FileField(upload_to='pdfs/', storage=AmazonS3PDFStorage())
    # user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class DisplayedPDF(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pdf_content = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    
class PDFfromS3File(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    s3_url = models.URLField()
```

viewCVpage.html

```
{% extends "layouts/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
<script defer type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'assets/js/popup-modal.js' %}"></script>
{% block title %} CV Upload Page {% endblock %} 

<!-- Specific CSS goes HERE -->
{% block stylesheets %}{% endblock stylesheets %}


{% block content %}
{% include 'customPage\modal\reassignModalPage.html' %}
<div class="pc-container">
    <div class="pcoded-content">
        <!-- [ breadcrumb ] start -->
        <div class="page-header">
            <div class="page-block">
                <div class="row align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="page-header-title">
                            <h5 class="m-b-10">Dashboard sale</h5>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="breadcrumb">
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item">View CV Page</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="card flat-card">
        <div class="row-table">
            <div class="col-sm-6 card-body br">
                <div class="row">
                        <h1>This is CV view page</h1>
                        
                            
                            <table class="table table-dark table-hover">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="viewCVth">Title</th>
                                        <th class="viewCVth">PDF Content</th>
                                        <th class="viewCVth-action"><b>Action</b></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <a href="{% url 'display_pdf_list' %}">View PDF List</a>
                                
                                <tbody>
                                    {% for pdf in s3_data %}  {# Use s3_data instead of display_pdf_list #}
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="viewCVtd">{{ pdf.title }}</td>
                                            <td class="viewCVtd">
                                                {% if pdf.content %}
                                                <iframe src="{{ pdf.content }}" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>

                                                {% else %}
                                                    N/A
                                                {% endif %}
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="viewCVtd-action">
                                                <button class="actionButton btn-success">Approve</button>
                                                <button class="actionButton btn-primary" onclick="">Reassign</button>
                                                <button class="actionButton btn-info">View CV Details</button>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    {% endfor %}

                                    <p>currently still not showing the content of CV, work on filter first.</p>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            
                        <!-- </div> -->
                        <div id="modal" class="modal fade">
                            <div id="dialog" class="modal-dialog" hx-target="this"></div>

                            <div class="modal" id="modal">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                <!-- <div class="modal-content"> -->
                                    <!-- <form hx-post="{{ request.path }}" class="modal-content"> -->
                                    <form class="modal-content" id="modal-content">
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h5 class="modal-title">Reassign Staff</h5>
                                        </div>
                                        <select name="" id="">
                                            <option value="">Amelia Bennett</option>
                                            <option value="">Lucas Montgomery</option>
                                            <option value="">Sofia Rodriguez</option>
                                            <option value="">Jackson Patel</option>
                                            <option value="">Isabella Chang</option>
                                        </select>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                        {{ form.as_p }}
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                        <button type="submit">Save</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    </div>
</div>


{% endblock content %}

<!-- Specific Page JS goes HERE  -->
{% block scripts  %}
<script>
//     document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
//     var modal = document.querySelector('modal');
//     var modalContent = document.querySelector('modal-content');
//     var closeButton = document.querySelector('close');

//     closeButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
//         modal.style.display = 'none';
//     });

//     window.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
//         if (event.target === modal) {
//             modal.style.display = 'none';
//         }
//     });

// // Function to open the modal


//     // Call the openModal function to display the modal
//     openModal();
// function openModal() {
//     modal.style.display = 'block';
// }

//     // Call the openModal function to display the modal
//     openModal();
// });

// function openModal() {
//     modal.style.display = 'block';
// }

$(document).ready(function() {

// Get the modal
var modal = $('#modal');

// Open the modal
var button = $('#button-open-modal');
button.on('click', function(event) {
    modal.css('display', 'block');
})

// Close the modal
// var close_button = $('.close');
// close_button.on('click', function(event) {
//     modal.css('display', 'none');
// })

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
$(window).on('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target.id == modal.attr('id')) {
        modal.css('display', 'none');
    }
});

});
</script>
{% endblock scripts %}
```